# Java - Missing pixels at the right side of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I noticed that every JFrame I create doesnt show a few pixels - ~10px at the right side.
I dont know why that happens, but it could be very problematic for my game if I dont fix that.

Here is the code with which I am experimenting:

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Resizer {

    int width = 500;
    int height = 500;
    JFrame frame;
    JLabel screen;
    BufferedImage image;
    ImageIcon icon;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Resizer r = new Resizer();
        r.runCode();
    }


    private void runCode() {
        createFrame();

        javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(1000/60, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                checkResize();
                drawSomething();
            }
        });

        t.start();
    }


    private void createFrame() {

        frame = new JFrame("Resize Experiment");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        screen = new JLabel();
        screen.setSize(width, height);

        image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        icon = new ImageIcon(image);

        screen.setIcon(icon);
        frame.add(screen);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    private void checkResize() {
        if (frame.getWidth() != width || frame.getHeight() != height) {
            screen.setSize(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
            image = new BufferedImage(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

            frame.pack();
            width = frame.getWidth();
            height = frame.getHeight();
        }
    }


    private void drawSomething() {
        Graphics2D pen = image.createGraphics();
        pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        pen.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        pen.setColor(Color.RED);
        pen.drawLine(width, height/2, width-10, height/2);

        addImage();
    }


    private void addImage() {
        icon = new ImageIcon(image);
        screen.setIcon(icon);
    }

}
```

I noticed it because of the following statement:

```java
pen.drawLine(width, height/2, width-10, height/2);
```

It should draw a line from the right side of the JFrame to a place 10 pixel further to the left. In reality, I can't see any line at all. It appears once I raise the distance value.

My question is: Why does this happen, and how can I fix this?

Comment: You are way off in how you are using swing, and that probably accounts for the problems you are having. You should be doing all of your painting in paintComponent, and using the Swing timer for your game/animation loop

Comment: @ControlAltDel What makes the paintComponent approach better than Graphics2D? I really like how with Graphics2D things aren't stuffed in one method but can be split up.

Comment: paintComponent is better because it gets called every time the JComponent repaints itself. This can be from hiding/showing, moving, resizing, updating, etc. The framework for invalidating the GUI and then (re)validating is already there for you. Using paintComponent also ensures that your components are painted in the proper order (parent first, children later) and it also makes Swing thread safe (assuming you never call it on another thread)

Answer (score 0):

> I noticed that every JFrame I create doesnt show a few pixels - ~10px at the right side

That is because you are attempting to make your BufferedImage the size of the frame.

The problem is the frame contains "borders". Your image can only be painted inside the borders.

You should NOT be attempting to make the BufferedImage the size of the frame.

As suggested above the custom painting should be done in the paintComponent() method of a JPanel. Then you add the panel to the frame. Inside the paintComponent() method you can use the getWidth() and getHeight() methods of the panel to make sure you paint on the complete area.

> I really like how with Graphics2D things aren't stuffed in one method but can be split up

The custom painting done in the paintComponent() method is done with a Graphics2D object, so you can do anything you want. All Swing components are painted in the paintComponent() method.